# AfterFeature hook not working properly in specFlow

Tags: c#, binding, hook, bdd, specflow

I have 2 feature files with 2 step definition classes.Each class has methods with [AfterFeature] hook.While executing feature2, the method defined under [AfterFeature] hook in step definition file for feature1 gets invoked.

Answer (score 1):

The After Feature Hook in spec-flow is designed to be run after each feature. 
https://specflow.org/documentation/Hooks/
Shows the details of the hooks that can be used and they are designed to all be run before or after.

looking over their Definition you could Try adding a class level Scope Attribute ( Listed Here [Binding Documentation](https://specflow.org/documentation/scoped-bindings/)) to the class containing the AfterFeature step this may limit it but alas this is not the intended purpose. So i wouldn't overly expect this to work.

sorry its not the best answer in the world